# Live reload not possible in IDE since sql server not acccessible remotely

Tags: php, database, ftp, livereload

Scenario: PHP/mySQL web project hosted on remote server with FTP access
IDE: Atom
Problem: I want to be able to use live reload so that edits are instantly viewed in browser. This cannot be done since remote MySQL server is only accessible within domain - thus PDO/PHP cannot access data and web page cannot be created.

jscript and CSS can be edited live with Chrome debugger tools but requires copy/paste to upload changes with FTP.

Is there a solution to this scenario?